# Macro Program Very Slow

Tags: excel, vba

i need help. I have a program that extracts data from the workbooks listed in the listbox. The problem is the extraction takes time. Can you suggest a better solution? Thanks!

This is the code for extracting data:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Extract_Data()

Dim CurrentBook As Workbook
Dim WS, Sheet As Worksheet
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ALL DATA")
Dim i, j, LRow1, LRow2 As Long
Dim RangeToCopy As Range
Dim pc As PivotCache

'VBA Code Timer
Dim dTime As Double
dTime = Timer

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
.DisplayAlerts = False
.EnableEvents = False
End With

    For i = 0 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN").ListBox1.ListCount - 1
   
            Set CurrentBook = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN").ListBox1.List(i))
    
           
                    LRow1 = WS.Range("C" & WS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                    LRow2 = CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Range("C" & 
       CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                       
                    Set RangeToCopy = CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Range("D28:E" & LRow2 & ", 
         H28:H" & LRow2)
                         RangeToCopy.Copy
                    WS.Range("C" & LRow1 + 1).PasteSpecial 
         Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    
                       For j = 1 To LRow2 - 27
                            WS.Range("A" & LRow1 + j).Value2 = 
          CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Range("B10")
                       Next


            
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        CurrentBook.Close True
      
    Next i
    


  With Application
  .CutCopyMode = False
  .EnableEvents = True
  .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  .DisplayAlerts = True
  .ScreenUpdating = True
  End With

   Debug.Print "Time is: " & (Timer - dTime) * 1000
 End Sub
```

This is my program. I will click "Open File" to select workbooks
[image: This is my program. I will click "Open File" to select workbooks]

The selected files will appear in the listbox. When I click extract data,
[image: The selected files will appear in the listbox. When I click extract data,]

Data are extracted and pasted to Worksheet "ALL DATA" in columns A,C,D,E
[image: Data are extracted and pasted to Worksheet "ALL DATA" in columns A,C,D,E]

Comment: Which line(s) are taking the most time?  If it's the Workbook.Open or the two lines after it, there's not much you can do.  Opening workbooks takes time and there's no obvious way to speed this up.  If it's one of the lines after that, then you may be able to speed it up significantly, depending on which line it is.

Comment: Doesn't this code line `Set RangeToCopy = CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Range("D28:E" & LRow2 & ", H28:H" & LRow2)` return an error? Please confirm that the `NumberFormat` of the copied range is the same, or different on rows/columns.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I understand. I was hoping that at least there is another faster workaround. THank u :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Extract_Data()
    Dim CurrentBook As Workbook, WS As Worksheet, Sheet As Worksheet
    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ALL DATA")
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, LRow1 As Long, LRow2 As Long
    Dim arrCopy
    
    'VBA Code Timer
    Dim dTime As Double: dTime = Timer
       
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
     End With
   
    For i = 0 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN").ListBox1.ListCount - 1
                Set CurrentBook = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN").ListBox1.List(i))
                LRow1 = WS.Range("C" & WS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                LRow2 = CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Range("C" & CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                    
               arrCopy = CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Range("D28:E" & LRow2).Value2
               With WS.Range("C" & LRow1 + 1).Resize(UBound(arrCopy), UBound(arrCopy, 2))
                    .Value = arrCopy
                    .NumberFormat = CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Range("D28").NumberFormat
                End With
                arrCopy = CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Range("H28:H" & LRow2).Value2
               With WS.Range("E" & LRow1 + 1).Resize(UBound(arrCopy), UBound(arrCopy, 2))
                    .Value = arrCopy
                    .NumberFormat = CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Range("D28").NumberFormat
                End With
                           
                WS.Range("A" & LRow1 + 1 & ":A" & LRow2 - 27).Value2 = CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Range("B10").Value2
                
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                CurrentBook.Close False
    Next i
    
    With Application
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
 
    Debug.Print "Time is: " & (Timer - dTime) * 1000
    MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Comment: yes, all of the files have the same format. I tried your code but it was still slow. I guess I would have to agree with RBarryYoung's comment about the 'Workbook.Open' line. :(

Comment: @Daiichi_kun How much would you like it to take? I will improve it only to avoid pasting the format. But I am afraid that your problem is connected with a lot of formulae to be calculated after the code finishes...

Comment: @Daiichi_kun Please, test the updated code. It takes less than three seconds on my computer (since the links where the formulae points are broken). How much does it take on your computer? Does the duration of three seconds look too much for you?

Comment: @Daiichi_kun Did you test the updated code? If you still believe that the problem may be the workbook opening, I can adapt the code to grab the necessary data without opening the files. But, I would like to know how much does it take for the three test csv file, on your real situation...

Comment: Wow I tested the updated code, it took 58 seconds for 49 csv files! That is actually a lot of improvement compared to 10 minutes for 49 csv files! Though there will be times that I need to extract more than 100 csv files

Comment: Though I am planning to improve the work around again by just selecting the csv files in the open file dialog, not listing them in the listbox. I believe this will significantly imrpove the time.

Comment: I tested the code again, but this time I remove the formula after the code is executed, it took 28 secs for 49 csv files. It is a significant improvement, but it is still long (I have previous programs that took only a few seconds to extract data). I dont understand why is it still longer even if I removed the formulas